# The argument type 'List<Future<Sprite>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Sprite>'

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flame

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with HasTapableComponents {
  SpriteAnimationComponent girl = SpriteAnimationComponent();

  MyGame();
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final sprites = [0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      .map((i) async => await Sprite.load('Attack__00$i.png'))
      .toList();
    girl = SpriteAnimationComponent(
      animation: SpriteAnimation.spriteList(sprites, stepTime: 0.01),
      size: Vector2.all(100) 
    );
    add(girl);
    print(size);
  }
}
```

Following the github documents for flutter flame for the implementation of SpriteAnimationComponent,  `animation: SpriteAnimation.spriteList(sprites, ...)`.  The issue here as I've noticed is that the `sprites` are a Future list of sprites whereas spriteList requires a list of Sprites. Is this an issue in the docs, or am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the list of future sprites to materialize, like this:

```dart
final sprites = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
      .map((i) => Sprite.load('Attack__00$i.png'));
final animation = SpriteAnimation.spriteList(
  await Future.wait(sprites),
  stepTime: 0.01,
);
girl = SpriteAnimationComponent(
  animation: animation,
  size: Vector2.all(100) 
);
add(girl);
```

Edit: I can see that it is wrong in the docs, I'll update them.